# '_umul128': identifier not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compilation

In VS2010, I tested the following sample code of _umul128. The compile error occured:

"error C3861: '_umul128': identifier not found".

```
// umul128.c
// processor: IPF, x64

#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

#pragma intrinsic(_umul128)

int main()
{
    unsigned __int64 a = 0x0fffffffffffffffI64;
    unsigned __int64 b = 0xf0000000I64;
    unsigned __int64 c, d;

    d = _umul128(a, b, &c);

    printf_s("%#I64x * %#I64x = %#I64x%I64x\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

The source code is from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/3dayytw9(v=vs.100).aspx.

The OS is Windows8, 64-bit. Is it caused by compile environment? How to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error has been fixed by selecting x64 platform.
Thanks.